# why does it take FeedEK jquery plug it so long to get new RSS data

Tags: jquery, rss

I'm using FeedEK as an RSS parser on our website. It is getting its RSS feed from a Wordpress Blog. When a new Blog post is made, the RSS feed changes immediately but it takes a long time before the FeedEK parser shows the change.

Why?

Is there a way to force it to refresh?